# MSTest code coverage returns empty in UWP Application

Tags: c#, uwp, mstest

I have a problem with the code coverage of MSTest in my UWP Application.
Every time I try to run a coverage I get this result:
`Empty results generated: No binaries were instrumented. Make sure the tests ran, required binaries were loaded, had matching symbol files, and were not excluded through custom settings. For more information see https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=253731`

I have followed all the different troubleshooting things in the link above. But they don't seem to resolve it. I do not know what is causing this but here is some information related to my environment.

References of my Test project:

[image]

The *.pdb files of my references are present in the build directory of my Test project.

```
[TestClass]
    public class UnitModelTests
    {
        [DataTestMethod]

        #region Metric

        [DataRow(LengthMetric.MM, "1mm", UnitType.Metric)]
        [DataRow(LengthMetric.CM - LengthMetric.MM, "9mm", UnitType.Metric)]
        [DataRow(LengthMetric.CM, "1cm", UnitType.Metric)]
        [DataRow(LengthMetric.DM - LengthMetric.CM, "9cm", UnitType.Metric)]
        [DataRow(LengthMetric.DM, "1dm", UnitType.Metric)]
        [DataRow(LengthMetric.M - LengthMetric.DM, "9dm", UnitType.Metric)]
        [DataRow(LengthMetric.M, "1m", UnitType.Metric)]
        [DataRow(LengthMetric.KM - LengthMetric.M, "999m", UnitType.Metric)]
        [DataRow(LengthMetric.KM, "1km", UnitType.Metric)]
        [DataRow(LengthMetric.KM * 100, "100km", UnitType.Metric)]

        #endregion

        #region Imperial

        [DataRow(LengthImperial.Inch, "1 inch", UnitType.Imperial)]
        [DataRow(LengthImperial.Feet, "1 feet", UnitType.Imperial)]
        [DataRow(LengthImperial.Yard, "1 yard", UnitType.Imperial)]
        [DataRow(LengthImperial.Chain, "1 chain", UnitType.Imperial)]
        [DataRow(LengthImperial.Furlong, "1 furlong", UnitType.Imperial)]
        [DataRow(LengthImperial.Mile, "1 mile", UnitType.Imperial)]
        [DataRow(LengthImperial.League, "1 league", UnitType.Imperial)]

        #endregion

        public void LengthToStringTest(double startLength, string expected, UnitType unitType)
        {
            var length = new Length(startLength);
            Assert.AreEqual(expected, length.UnitToString(unitType));
        }

        [DataTestMethod]

        #region Metric

        [DataRow(VolumeMetric.MM, "1mm^3", UnitType.Metric)]
        [DataRow(VolumeMetric.MM * 9, "9mm^3", UnitType.Metric)]
        [DataRow(VolumeMetric.CM, "1cm^3", UnitType.Metric)]
        [DataRow(VolumeMetric.CM * 9, "9cm^3", UnitType.Metric)]
        [DataRow(VolumeMetric.DM, "1dm^3", UnitType.Metric)]
        [DataRow(VolumeMetric.DM * 9, "9dm^3", UnitType.Metric)]
        [DataRow(VolumeMetric.M, "1m^3", UnitType.Metric)]
        [DataRow(VolumeMetric.M * 999, "999m^3", UnitType.Metric)]
        [DataRow(VolumeMetric.KM, "1km^3", UnitType.Metric)]
        [DataRow(VolumeMetric.KM * 100, "100km^3", UnitType.Metric)]

        #endregion

        #region Imperial

        [DataRow(VolumeImperial.FluidOunce, "1 Fluid ounce", UnitType.Imperial)]
        [DataRow(VolumeImperial.Gill, "1 Gill", UnitType.Imperial)]
        [DataRow(VolumeImperial.Pint, "1 Pint", UnitType.Imperial)]
        [DataRow(VolumeImperial.Quart, "1 Quart", UnitType.Imperial)]
        [DataRow(VolumeImperial.Gallon, "1 Gallon", UnitType.Imperial)]

        #endregion

        public void VolumeToStringTest(double startVolume, string expected, UnitType unitType)
        {
            var volume = new Volume(startVolume);
            Assert.AreEqual(expected, volume.UnitToString(unitType));
        }
    }
```

Test Results:
All tests that are shown here return as successful.

Build configuration:

[image: Build Configuration]

NuGet Packages of the MSTest project:
[image: NuGet Packages]

If more information is needed please leave a comment.

Comment: I think that a UWP project doesn't support Code Coverage. but I am not sure about it.

Comment: Yep, my suspicions are right. There isn't code coverage 'yet' for UWP applications. Luckily I found a solution. Instead of using a Class Libary for UWP, you can use a .NET Standard  Class Library. Then you use the MSTest project for .Net Core to test that class.  Well, there goes my time. I only found it after using Google instead of DuckDuckGo. Here is the link to the solution: https://www.redgreencode.com/unit-testing-uwp-apps/#:~:text=Code%20coverage%20is%20not%20supported,going%20back%20a%20few%20years.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The UWP MSTest implementation currently does not support code coverage. [Here](https://www.redgreencode.com/unit-testing-uwp-apps/#:%7E:text=Code%20coverage%20is%20not%20supported,going%20back%20a%20few%20years) is a link to a blog that talks about it. A workaround could be to change the `UWP Class Libary` to a `.NET Standard Class Libary`. Then change the `UWP MSTest project` to the `.NET Core` variant. After changing this and running the code coverage via test explorer you get the results you wanted.
[image]

For a better explanation about this issue, you can visit this website that talks about it. https://www.redgreencode.com/unit-testing-uwp-apps/